# Add a new trusted CA to Netbeans SVN manager

Tags: svn, netbeans, ssl, certificate, ca

So I have a private SVN server for my company that has its own self signed certificate, it was signed by the company CA, I have the CA certificate and I want to add it to the list of default trusted CAs in the Netbeans SVN client. I have tried adding it to the windows trusted CA list and it works fine for the windows stuff, and I have added it to the JRE/JDK keystore using keytool and it works in eclipse but I can't seem to find any information on what keystore netbeans uses so I can add a new CA to it. Also the Accept Permanently option doesn't work so I can't use that either for some reason so I'd really like to learn how to add this cert to netbeans if anyone knows.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem with NB 6.8/6.9. I am not sure whether it's the case with 7.0.

I solved it by checking out the repo manually using command line client and picked the option "trust permanently" (not sure about the precise name).

It creates certificate file in following location:

```
$HOME/.subversion/auth/svn.ssl.server/
```

Use this file in NB svn dialog as "Client certificate file".

Comment: Thanks it doesn't bother me anymore now that I specified the Client certificate file, I was trying to specify the ca.crt the first time around and it wasn't working.